# Remove specific image from a string

Tags: php, html, string, preg-replace

I want to remove specific image from string.

I need to remove Image with specific width and height.

I have tried this, but this will remove first image.

```
$description = preg_replace('/<img.*?>/', '123', $description, 1);
```

I want to remove any/all image(s) with specific width and height.
E.g. Remove this image `<img width="1" height="1" ..../>`

Comment: From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php): `preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )`, you are setting a limit of 1 to your preg_replace. However, with that code you will be removing *all* images, do you really just want a particular subset of images removed?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove particular images only. Not all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you move away from using regex expressions to parse (or manipulate) HTML, because it's not a good idea, [and here's a great SO answer on why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

For example, by using Peter's approach (`preg_match_all('~<img src="(.+?)" width="(.+?)">~is', $content, $return);`), you are assuming that all your images start with `<img`, are followed by the `src`, and then contain the `width=`, all typed exactly like that and with those exact whitespace separations, and those particular quotes. That means that you will not capture any of these perfectly valid HTML images that you want to remove:

`<img src='asd' width="123">
<img src="asd"  width="123">
<img src="asd" class='abc' width="123">
<img src="asd" width = "123">`

While it's of course perfectly possible to catch all these cases, do you really want to go through all that effort? Why reinvent the wheel when you can just parse the HTML with already-existing tools. Take a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

Made a little example for you

```
<?php

$string = 'something something <img src="test.jpg" width="10" height="10" /> and something .. and <img src="test.jpg" width="10" height="10" /> and more and more and more';
preg_match_all('~<img(.+?)width="10"(.+?)height="10"(.+?)/>~is', $string, $return);

foreach ($return[0] as $image) {
    $string = str_replace($image, '', $string);
}

echo $string;
```

Comment: Try to run  your example for the string: `<img src='abcd'></img>More stuff<img class='test' width="10" height="10"></img>`. You will remove the whole thing.

Comment: end your img tags with ' />' and not </img>

Comment: @Think And play around with the preg_match a bit to let it fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:

```
$description = preg_replace('!<img.*?width="1".*?/>!i', '', $description);
```